# Convert object datatype of multiple columns into an integer on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Please help :

I have bellow a dataset looking like in the images

[enter image description here][1]

I would like to convert columns into integers but still conserve the column names as strings, and I have many many columns so I can't do it my writing each column name.

I tried lambda expressions, if statements but nothing seems to work

would appreciate any clue
Many thanks

Comment: Please add your code and actually include the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is here. If you want to convert all columns to `int`, you can do

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

This doesn't convert your column headers to `int`, just the values. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '0': ['1', '2', '3']
})

df = df.astype(int)

df['0']  # <-- this works

df[0]  # <-- this results in Key Error
```

In case your headers are already integers, you can do `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)`